# no targets specified and no makefile found. stop

Tags: command-line

I have a problem here u go, I want to install qtractor.
I wrote in terminal

```
cd /home/hl/Documenten/qtractor-0.6.0
```

after that i did  write and enter:

```
sh ./configure
```

this is what i get.

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for Qt library version >= 4.4... no; Qt 4.4 or greater is required
```

after this i write and enter make

```
no targets specified and no makefile found. stop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is a dependency problem: you do not have the qt4 libraries installed.

Install all dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
sudo apt-get install libjack0
sudo apt-get install libjack-dev
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
```

Now, run:

```
./configure
```

after, type:

```
make
```

and finally:

```
sudo make install
```