# Compile Dogecoin wallet

Tags: 14.04

I need to install and run `dogecoind`, but I always encounter an error with `makefile.unix`.
I have already installed Litecoin and it works perfectly, but Dogecoin does not. It seems `makefile.unix` and `dogecoind` in `/src/` do not exist. See https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/tree/master/src.

I use Ubuntu 14.04, and have done this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libdb-dev libdb++-dev libqrencode-dev qt4-qmake libqtgui4 libqt4-dev git
sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev libminiupnpc8 libboost-all-dev build-essential git  libboost1.48-all-dev

git clone https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin

cd dogecoin

qmake USE_UPNP=-
=> I have msg: qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

make
=> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

make -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP=-
=> make: makefile.unix: No such file or directory
=> make: *** No rule to make target `makefile.unix'.  Stop.
```

I have tried with qt4 ([no targets specified and no makefile found. stop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454730/no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile-found-stop)) but I get an error.

```
./configure
=> bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you read the `doc/build-unix.md` instructions, as suggested in the `INSTALL` file? They indicate that you need to run `./autogen.sh` **first** to create the `./configure` script.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve "I have msg: qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''", run:

apt-get install qt5-default

Comment: I don't think that's the issue - they don't have a make file or a configure script run, and that's part of the compile instructions (see the comment on the question itself)